# MySQL Relevance Search with DataTable Filter

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, ado

We want to be able to return 'suggestions' of sorts from our database in our WinForms application based on tags that our program creates when users create issues, tickets, etc.

The SQL we use to pull this information is easy enough when done with SQL:

```
SET @termz='random words influence topics';
SELECT _TABLE_.*, MATCH (term, description) AGAINST (@termz) AS relevance, MATCH (term) AGAINST (@termz) AS title_relevance
FROM _TABLE_
WHERE MATCH (term, description) AGAINST (@termz IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
HAVING title_relevance > 5
ORDER BY title_relevance DESC, relevance DESC;
```

However, I would ASSUME that constantly sending a query such as the above, even in a stored procedure call, with every ticket created, or every keystroke (for live searches or live suggestions, for example), would be a useabilty 'sin' as you people here so famously keep terming it.

So, I would assume, that I'd need to just run these types of queries against a local, disconnected DataSet, and return results based on that.  As it doesn't have to query the actual database each time, I can just create a filter or view, to use, and then populate whatever lists, etc, people can use to read relevant information.

But, how would one write a filter/view like the above?  Is it even possible?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support materialized views, so that's not what you want.  If this query is bothering you, I'd suggest either precalculating (and caching) if you can, or using a real text search engine.

Comment: Huh! I've never seen the word "sin" used here. There's nothing wrong with your query's logic. Are you actually having performance problems with it? Or are you borrowing trouble from the future?  Note that if you get rid of the use of `*` in favor of the columns you actually need in your `SELECT` you may get improved performance. Also notice that you can buy a *lot* of MySQL boxes for the price of a commercial text search engine.